# Remove all characters after the last letter of the string JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to remove all characters after the last letter inside a string. E.g. this is a string that I'd like to edit:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog   |   \ +   ! ?";
```

What I want to display is this:

```
var foo = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

"g" being the last letter, but I don't want to hardcode it, I want to make it work if there's any letter that's on the last position.

Is there a RegExp pattern or a plugin which would do the job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match that portion by:

```
[^A-Za-z]*$
```

and use null string in replacement.

- `[^A-Za-z]*` matches any character except letters zero or more times at the end of the line (`$`)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FGtzrN/1)

Comment: Hey mate, a quick question - how can I change the 'A-Za-z' regular expression to be any character except '|'   -  vertical bar?

Comment: @kneles90 do `[^|]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  ([A-Za-z])(?!.*[A-Za-z]).*
```

and replace by

```
\1
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/qtxgXg/2)

1. ([A-Za-z]) matches a alphabet
2. (?!.*[A-Za-z]) see if the the character followed by no alphabet
3. if yes then captures the result of the line

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/5P92A3/1) will match from first non-letter character from any language to `";` and won't include these to keep the string intact.

```
[^\pL]*?(?=";)
```

Then just replace by empty string. Note that you need the unicode flag `u` for the any language thing to work. If you just need ASCII characters you can replace `\pL` with `a-zA-Z`.

- `[^\pL]` finds first non letter character, `\pL` matches any letter in any language
- `*?` finds all next non letter characters
- `(?=";)` is a positive lookahead which means the match will stop when next characters are `";`, when the string has ended.

Comment: `[^\pL]` can be written `\PL`.